# What I need to modify to fix this textarea in post-modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a front end posting with modal box and has a problem. I don't know how to explain this problem because I still learn english and it's hard for my but I will try, also i make screenshot maybe you will understand better from that

In my modal box i have a `textarea` for title post and has `class="form-controll`" when you drag of `textarea` You can not see well meaning override modal box.

I make screenshots.
I want to know what I need to modifiy in css for this.

[image]

Thanks and again sorry for my english.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: from css? i need to search a little bit if it's that because Isn't my theme make the theme, I buy it and I need to search in css for modal-post.

Comment: Post both the css and html code that you have or have seen

Comment: This is html: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5555 and this is css: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5556 it's all I found about modal-post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it with this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <textarea class="form-control col-xs-12" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

and this:

```
.modal-content textarea.form-control {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```